# How to apply modifier to collections

Tags: modifiers, objects, particles, groups, collections

Good morning, everyone,

I'm currently on a project to make a small LEGO animation on Blender. I wanted to make a city with LEGO buildings as below.

[image]

The problem is that these buildings are built one piece by one piece (which is the principle of LEGO) and therefore a different object for each piece, so it takes a lot of space in memory. I tried to join them into one object (with Ctrl + J) for a whole building in vain because the computer crashes each time.
I then group them together in a collection, but I can't apply modifiers like the Array which only multiplies one object, so only one piece (which would be a bit long to apply an Array on each room).
For the Particle Sytem, I could check the Collection box in Render, then Whole Collection. The problem is that I would then have a Particle System with only one building, which would miss a bit of diversity for the job.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how I could get out of it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can apply most of the modifiers by selecting them then press alt+c and select mesh from curve.... This works with multiple objects too.

Comment: can you please tell whether you want to apply modifiers of an object to the collection or you want to delete particle system ?\

Comment: Hi @FFeller ! I tried to gather all my objects and convert them to mesh from curve, but it doesn't work, and I take the example of the Array, it always only multiplies one object by one object.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. I just want to apply a particle system to all my buildings, where each building is a different collection. @JacksonPro